# Handwriting Recognition for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm planning to do a handwriting recognition application for WP7 in next graduating report. The only time its left more than a month not enought to study from the beginning. I plan to use SVM, but also don't know much about it. If some one has done this, please guide me. Thank you so much !